# Merging two datasets with a different number of observations

Tags: r

### -2 datasets
-18 observations per municipality
-One dataset has more municipalities included than the other (14940 vs 13014, which means there are 1926/18=107 municipalities more included in one dataset than the other
-I need to find a way to merge the datasets, so to remove the 107 municipalities so that they both have the same number of observations.

My question is, how do I do this? I am really not very experienced in R, but I need this dataset for my thesis and I have been struggling for a while now.
-I think I need to identify what 107 municipalities are included in the bigger dataset
-And then remove them
-Is there an easy way to do this?

[Picture of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp5D8.png)

Both datasets look exactly alike, apart from the above described problem. Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [introduction to dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html), which answers how datasets can be merged via joins in R.

This is also a good starting point to get a handle on data manipulation with R.